# Making two divs with their own scrolling/interactivity sit on top of one another on mobile

Tags: html, css

I've been working back and forth with this code for a while and I can't seem to get the `sidebar` and `map` class to sit one on top of the other (like responsive bootstarap style) on mobile. I don't want to use bootstrap, but I have it exactly as I want it on desktop, I'm just trying to make the `sidebar` and `map`  sit full-width but only a portion of the height for mobile. The sidebar is a scrolling box of listings while the map class just holds a JS map widget but I just want them to sit on top of each other on mobile

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<style>

      body {
        color: #404040;
        font: 400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height:100%;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      @media (max-width: 767px) {
      
      .map_wrapper {
          flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }
        .sidebar,
        .map {
          width: auto;
        }
      }

      .map_wrapper{
        display: flex;
      }

      .sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 15%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 20%;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }

      .map {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 20%;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding: 20px 2px;
      }

      a {
        color: #404040;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      a:hover {
        color: #101010;
      }

      .heading {
        background: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        min-height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        background-color: #88B942;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .listings {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
      }

      .listings .item {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .listings .item:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
      .listings .item .title {
        display: block;
        color: #88B942;
        font-weight: 700;
      }

      .listings .item .title small {
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      .listings .item.active .title,
      .listings .item .title:hover {
        color: #8cc63f;
      }
      .listings .item.active {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
      }
      ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 3px;
        height: 3px;
        border-left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: none;
      }
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #88B942;
        border-radius: 0;
      }

      .marker {
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 56px;
        width: 56px;
        background-image: url(https://cannabis.page/images/WEED_MARKER_final.png);
      }

      /* Marker tweaks */
      .mapboxgl-popup {
        padding-bottom: 50px;
      }

      .mapboxgl-popup-close-button {
        display: none;
      }
      .mapboxgl-popup-content {
        font: 400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        width: 180px;
      }
      .mapboxgl-popup-content h3 {
        background: #91c949;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-top: -15px;
      }

      .mapboxgl-popup-content h4 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }

      .mapboxgl-popup-content div {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-content {
        margin-top: 15px;
      }

      .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
        border-bottom-color: #91c949;
      }

      .round {
        display: inline-block !important;
        margin: 0 auto;
          width: 90%;
          border-radius: 15px;
          border: 1px #000 solid;
          padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 5;
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          width: 30%;
      }

      input[type="submit"] {
        display: inline-block;
          margin-left: -63px;
          height: 34px;
          background: blue;
          color: white;
          border: 0;
          background-color: #88B942;
          -webkit-appearance: none;
      }
    
</style>
      <div class="box" style="text-align:center;">
        <input id="zipSearch" type="text" name="search" class="round" onclick="getLocation()" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" />
        <input type="submit" name="" onclick="getByManualZip()">
      </div>

     


      <div class="map_wrapper" style="border: 1px solid red;width:70% !important; display: flex; margin: 0 auto !important;">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="heading">
            <h1>Our locations</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="listings" class="listings">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map" class="map" style="border:1px solid black">
        Placeholder for map
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: I assume by 'on top of' you mean 'above' as opposed to literally having both index layered with a `z-index`.

For this, the first thing you'll want to do is swap your `position` from `absolute` to `relative`. Then it's really just a matter of setting `width: 100%` and getting rid of the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` values, which you can overwrite with `auto`.

There's some additional styling that can be done, like adding a `margin` to the elements. Note that in your example above, the `.map_wrapper` has an `!important` declaration inline. These should be avoided, as they add the highest possible level of [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). I've moved these inline styles to the CSS panel to allow my styles to override them.

See `NEW` in the styles below:

```css
body {
  color: #404040;
  font: 400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .map_wrapper {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .sidebar,
  .map {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.map_wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 2px;
}

a {
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #101010;
}

.heading {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  min-height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #88B942;
  color: #fff;
}

.listings {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.listings .item {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.listings .item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.listings .item .title {
  display: block;
  color: #88B942;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.listings .item .title small {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.listings .item.active .title,
.listings .item .title:hover {
  color: #8cc63f;
}

.listings .item.active {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  border-left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #88B942;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.marker {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  background-image: url(https://cannabis.page/images/WEED_MARKER_final.png);
}


/* Marker tweaks */

.mapboxgl-popup {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-close-button {
  display: none;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  font: 400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content h3 {
  background: #91c949;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top>.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top>.mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-bottom-color: #91c949;
}

.round {
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -63px;
  height: 34px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #88B942;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/* NEW */

.map_wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .map_wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .sidebar,
  .map {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .listings {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="text-align:center;">
  <input id="zipSearch" type="text" name="search" class="round" onclick="getLocation()" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" />
  <input type="submit" name="" onclick="getByManualZip()">
</div>

<div class="map_wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Our locations</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="listings" class="listings">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map" class="map" style="border:1px solid black">
    Placeholder for map
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much!